# Hyphenation doesn't work if the word is inside brackets and bold

Tags: hyphenation, bold, brackets

So, the hyphenation apparently doesn't work, if the word is inside of round brackets AND in bold font.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung (\textbf{Vorkonditionierung})

Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: hyphenation error]

Is this supposed to happen? How can I get the hypenation to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you can re-enable it via

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung (\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}\textbf{Vorkonditionierung})

Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung Vorkonditionierung
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this the way it is supposed to work? I find it very odd that you would have to re-enable hyphenation. Why would hyphenation be disabled in the first place? It works fine if you use just brackets or just bold text, so why not with both combined?

Comment: @LukasFun I'd have to read the texbook again but I think it's same as if you change font within the word, which also disables hyphenation, the strings considered are (more or less) space delimited strings in the same font then ignore punctuation.